# Podfile platform version is not updated on cordova prepare

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods, ionic5

I've an Ionic Cordova hybrid project. I try to update the iOS version platform in Podfile but I cannot change the version. By default, Cordova set 'platform :ios, '11.0', but I have a dependency needing a minimum of iOS 12.4.

I put in my config.xml =>

```
<platform name="ios">
   <preference name="deployment-target" value="12.4"/>
...
</platform>
```

My Podfile auto-generated =>
...
platform :ios '11.0'
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, i had got one plugin with plugin.xml with custom preference

This plugin overload my configuration

Answer (score 0):

Your minimum deployment target is already 11. Which is less than 12.4. But still if you want to change it. Then open ProjectFolder>Platform>ios>myApp.xcworkspace in Xcode and change from Build settings

Comment: Thanks, i know. But i want to modify without modify xcode project. It's a hybrid project. So i would like modify Podfile from cordova prepare/build

Comment: @YannaY Set this line in Config.xml 
 `<preference name="deployment-target" value="12.4"/>` 
Now remove ios platfrom ,
clean cache ,
Add ios platform again 
Try this it may work for you.

Comment: Hello no, i repeat, this method doesn't change the podfile version.

Comment: @YannaY did you find solution ? i am looking for same

Comment: @VikasKalapur, yes, below my answer: one cordova plugin oveloaded my configuration. I fork this plugin

Answer (score 0):

The podfile is generated from cordova-ios, and the platform version must be change manually in Podfile.